# Xampp install amqp extension for Symfony project

Tags: xampp, amqp

I am trying to enable the amqp extension for xampp . I did downloaded the dll , saved it on php/ext and copyied the rappid file to System32 and SystemWOW .  Added the extension line on php.ini file and restarted the apache server but i get this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URMwa.jpg) . Any suggestions ?

I am new here so if the questions is a bit "noobish" , i am sorry about it but i cant find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's version you install the [amqp](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp) and what's the PHP version

Comment: I just needed to update xampp and it worked after that .

Comment: @Ben Good news.